# What size to use in UIViewController's loadView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

My container `UIViewController` is going to add another `CustomViewController`'s view to its view hierarchy. It first creates the controller, then resizes its view, and finally adds it to its view.

```
    //create the controller
    customController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [customController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:customController];
    [customController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //size and position the controller's view 
    customController.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50);

    //add the new controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:customController.view];
    [customController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

The re-sizing part is my problem.

The `CustomViewController` creates its view programmatically in `loadView`, where a number of subviews are added. Since the CustomViewController doesn't really know how it's view will end up being sized/positioned, it initializes using simply `init` (no frame is provided).

This works fine for a simple UIView, but as soon as I add subviews, I have a problem. Placing those subviews inside `loadView' won't really work since the frame is CGRectZero. Furthermore, once I set up the autoresizing masks to make sure it scales properly, the end result is that all subviews grow to occupy the entire view. Probably because the co-ordinates of the subviews are all 100% of the view's frame (because the view's frame is CGRectZero).

In short, what size frame am I supposed to use in `loadView`? Should I just assume a typical view size that I expect the view to occupy? Or is there a better approach that allows me to add subviews but defer the sizing of the controller's view?

Answer (score 1):

View of the UIViewController has actual size in viewWillAppear method (method of UIViewController's lifecycle). So you may subclass UIViewController class and layout your subviews there.

But, I want to give you some recomendations.
You should use loadView method of the view controller to create it's view. 
Otherwise you may encounter memory management problems and problems with views layout.
Calling view properties in init method is not very good idea, because it automatically call loadView method of UIViewController..

Read more about UIViewController's lifecycle. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

My suggestions:
use loadView of parent UIViewController to create it's view.
Layout view in viewWillAppear.

Good luck! If you have questions, ask more:)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the frames for your subviews in relation to their superview. Like

```
subview.frame = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width *0.2,  self.view.frame.size.height *0.2, self.view.frame.size.width *0.8, self.view.frame.size.height *0.8);
```